# Drawing with CGContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

I'm trying to draw lines through `touchesMove:` method.

Below is my `touchesMoved:`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// context setting
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 255, 0, 0, 0.5);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);

// drawing
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGContextFlush(context);
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The `touchesMoved:` is invoked; However nothing is shown on the screen.

What am I missing?

**Added**

self is a subclass of UIImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found why it wasn't working. I created `CGContext` every touch move event. I moved the line `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);` to `init` method and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();` to `dealloc`.

Here's the code how I drawing.

```
static CGPoint lastPoint;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch_ = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point_  = [touch_ locationInView:self];

    lastPoint = point_;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // context setting
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    lastPoint = CGPointZero;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // drawing
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextFlush(context);
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
```