# Drawing CGContext Line with TouchesMoved in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm creating a ball swiping game for iOS in Objective-C where you swipe the screen and the ball moves. I have it set so that the ball moves in the opposite direction of where you swipe. For example, if I swipe down and release, the ball moves up.

I created a line to show the direction of where the ball would move using CGContext. The line starts from the center of the ball(ball.center.x, ball.center.y) to the point where you swipe with your finger(movePoint). I am trying to have it so when I swipe the screen, instead of having it draw a line to movePoint, it would draw a line in the opposite direction. For example, if I swipe down on the screen, a line would be drawn upwards.

I have tried fiddling around with the coordinate system but I can't seem to get it properly point in the opposite direction of where I swiped. Is there any particular approach to go about this?

Thank you.

Here is my touchesMoved function:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    movePoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([ball frame], firstPoint)) {
        _contextImage.hidden = NO;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, ball.center.x, ball.center.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, movePoint.x, movePoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

        self.contextImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: i hope this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150674/drawing-with-cgcontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the delta-X from the ball's center to the touch location would be `movePoint.x - ball.center.x`. Another way to put that is that the X coordinate of the touch location is `ball.center.x + (movePoint.x - ball.center.x)`, right? Well, the point in the opposite direction is computed by subtracting instead of adding (or, put another way, by negating the delta-X): `ball.center.x - (movePoint.x - ball.center.x)`.

The same would be true of the Y location: `ball.center.y - (movePoint.y - ball.center.y)`.

So, draw your line to there.